# Best Code Practice Validation - C

Tags: c

Have some variables that I need to perform validation on. Pseudocode is as follows but I feel there must be a more elegant soloution.

```
  If ( var != A || var != B || var != C || var != D )
        {
        reject
        }
    else if ( var == A || var == B)
        {
        do validation applicable to A or B
        }
    else if ( var == A || var == B || var == C || var == D )  
        {
        do validation applicable to all valid vars
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean "==" instead of "=" ?

Comment: How delightfully underhanded.

Comment: Did you mean "&&" instead of "||" ? ... oops, did I spoil something?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant ==. And || is correct - validation only applies if it is one of the four

Comment: To avoid mistakes like using = instead of ==, I prefer comparing like this `if (A == var || B == var) 
{ 
  // do something 
}`

Comment: Well in "pseudocode" "=" is as valid as "==" because the language is illustrative, however having tagged it as C, you would do better to use "realcode".  If you meant "==" edit the question!

Comment: @wildplasser && would mean var = A == B == C == D and thus testing each separately is not really useful...

Comment: The psudocode is flawed.  If var == A or var == B, the only the "*do validation applicable to A or B*" will be executed regardless of the value of C or D.

Comment: If A and B are unequal, then *at least* one of `var!=A` and `var!=B` is true. If A and B are equal the statement makes no sense.

Comment: The reject clause is *always* executed because var cannot be equal to A,B,C,and D simultaneously, so at least three of the != operations will be true!  The && operator *is* required in the first condition.

Comment: @CVD: Writing backwards makes it really hard to read code, as it is the opposite of how you would normally express yourself. For example, I read `if (2 > a)` as "if '2' is exceptionally large...". Try to use a text editor that can highlight assignments inside expressions, like Emacs does when you use `cwarn-mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original pseudocode is incorrect, so I have made some reasonable assumptions about the required behaviour.

```
// If var not equal to any of A,B,C or D...
if ( var != A && var != B && var != C && var != D ) 
{
    reject
}
// Otherwise var equal to one of A,B,C or D
else
{
    // If it is A or B...
    if( var == A || var == B )
    {
        do validation applicable to A or B
    }

    do validation applicable to all valid vars
}
```

Or you could flip the logic as follows:

```
// If var equal to one of A,B,C or D
if( var == A || var == B || var == C || var == D ) 
{
    // If it is A or B...
    if( var == A || var == B )
    {
        do validation applicable to A or B
    }

    do validation applicable to all valid vars
}
else
{
    reject
}
```

which may be clearer.

Comment: Pseudocode is indeed incorrect. Maybe plain english would have been a better option. This looks like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

How about `switch`:

```
switch (var)
{
    case A:
    case B:
        validate_ab();
        // break here if desired
    case C:
    case D:
        validate_all();
        break;
    default:
        reject();
 }
```

This requires `var` to have an integral type, though.

Comment: This is not OK since this will not validate_all in case of A or B.

Comment: @Eregrith:  Neither will the original pseudocode.

Comment: @Eregrith: Indeed, fixed - thanks!

Comment: @Clifford indeed, the `else if` prevents it ... I think the question author did not mean to do that error :)

Comment: @Eregrith: I have made that assumption (and others) in my answer.

Comment: I added a comment that there could be a `break;` if the ALL check should not be done for AB. The pseudo-code is a bit misleading, as currently the final `var == A || var == B` can never be met.

Comment: @Kerrek:  Its worse than that, the first condition will cause all values of var to be rejected, the `||`s need to be `&&`s

Comment: @Clifford: Oh, of course! I hadn't even noticed that... Hm, not sure what to do now. Surely `reject()` isn't the answer the OP was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( var < 'A' || var > 'D' )
    {
    reject
    }
else if ( var < 'C')
    {
    do validation applicable to A or B
    }
else  
    {
    do validation applicable to all valid vars
    }
```

Comment: The var will be a string so can't use < or >

Comment: in C string is not there. and if var is a char array then we can replace var with var[i]

Comment: You are assuming at A,B,C,D are characters rather than symbols.  If that were the case they'd hardly need any further validation, so it seems unlikely.

Comment: @paper:  But it was *pseudocode*; you cannot apply C syntax and semantics to it!  You have take take it in the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the kind of values that var can take ofcourse but if possible why not try to make it with bitflags? Let's assume it's an int for the example and it can contain any of the bitflags A,B,C,D.

```
#define A 0x01
#define B 0x02
#define C 0x04
#define D 0x08
if((var & (int)0xF) == 0)
{
   //reject
}
else if(var &(int) 0x3 != 0)
{
 //applicable only to A or B
}
else if((var & (int)0xF) != 0)
{
    //do validation applicable to all valid vars
}
```

You might not be able to utilize bitflags in your particular application but if you can it would be of benefit to you to do it similar to the example I gave.

Answer (score 0):

I think using switch is good option. Below is what i though of a readable code

```
int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
switch(var){
 case A : 
     a=1;
 if(b && c && d)
    do validate applicable to all valid vars
    else if(b)
    do validation applicable to A or B   
    return;
case B :
    b=1;
    if(a && c && d)
        do validate applicable to all valid vars
    else if(a)
        do validation applicable to A or B   
    return;
 case C :
    c=1;
    if(a && b && d)
        do validate applicable to all valid vars
    return;
 case D :
    d=1;
    if(a && b && c)
        do validate applicable to all valid vars
    return;
 default :
    reject;
    return;
}
```